# Alternative to call php in java script?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I want to call php  in a java script

I have read that this is forbidden:

```
document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML="<?php include my.php?>";
```

if I can't do this How can I load a php page content to a div with `id1` when clicking an  `li`:

```
<ul>
 <li onclick="javascriptFunction()">
 <li>
 <li>
</ul>
<div id="id1"></div>
```

Comment: that could work dependences on what is in my.php. and that the page is php parsed. the other alternative is ajax

Comment: Forbidden because it wouldn't work anyway. Syntax errors.

Comment: @Dagon, my.php may contains html code and php code :`<html> <?php ?></html>`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, forbidden

Comment: PHP is executed on the server, JS is run on the client (usually the web browser) and HTML is interpreted on the client. This means that you can not execute a PHP script on the client; You try to do exactly that. This comment is meant as a clarification, the AJAX answers below are a good approach.

Comment: Non sense, why cannot simply hide the div then make it visible when you want the visitor to see the content? Simple and no ajax involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of achieving the goal.

It isn't so much that what you are trying to do is *forbidden* as much as it is simply impossible.

**Option 1**

Use an `ajax` call to  your PHP code.  In the callback of the ajax call, fill in the innerHTML.

**Option 2**

Use a template.

```
<script type="text/html" id="template-id1">
  <?php include my.php?>
</script>


<li onclick="setDiv()">

<script>
  function setDiv() {
    document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML =
      document.getElementById("template-id1").innerHTML;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax).

With a usage of library like jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you will have code like this:

```
$.ajax('my.php')
    .done(function(response) {
         $('#id1').html(response);
    })
```

Of course it's doable without any libraries like jQuery, but just requires a bit more code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that'd be forbidden. It's called [bootstrapping](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#bootstrapping_data).

But if you must:

my.php

```
echo 'whatever';
```

And then in a `<script>` tag, use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to call my.php and fill the appropriate element with the response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax, if you don't want to use library try this:

```
var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

request.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML=request.responseText;
    }
};

request.open("GET","my.php",true);
request.send();
```

Or you could hide the div, then when you click on the link then make it visible.

```
<div id='id1' style='display:none;'>
    your content
</div>

function javascriptFunction() {
    document.getElementById('id1').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ready function:

```js
function javascriptFunction () {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'my.php', true);
    xhr.send();
}
```